# How to change the font family for tick labels in pgfplots + beamer + professionalfonts?

Tags: beamer, pgfplots

I am making a beamer presentation with some pgfplots figures and I want to change the font family to sans serif for all tick labels. The problem is that it doesn't work for the y-axis as you can see below. It works if I don't use the 'professionalfonts' font theme but I need it. It also works for normal axis instead of semilogyaxis. Is this a bug?

I use the very latest 1.12.1 revision of pgfplots.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogyaxis}[tick label style={/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true,font=\sffamily}]
    \end{semilogyaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

% this works but I want to use 'semilogyaxis'
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[tick label style={/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true,font=\sffamily}]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

labels of the y-axis are not sans serif:
[image]

this is how it should look like (comment '\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}' out):
[image]

Comment: IMHO it's not a bug. The purpose of the `professionalfonts` theme is explicitly to *not* mess with the fonts in any way, assuming the user has set them up the way he/she wants. This means the normal `beamer` font substitution (using sans serif math) does not happen when `professionalfonts` is used. Because no math font was set up in the code, the default Computer Modern (serif) math font is used.

Comment: Consider that the same thing also happens with just `\begin{frame}
$e = mc^2$
\end{frame}`, it may help to think about it without `pgfplots` involved at all.

Comment: Thanks for you comment but everything works as expected for non-logarithmic axis. '/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true' should remove the math mode flags but it doesn't (at least for log. axis).

Comment: Because the log axis *has* to use math mode to typeset exponents.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the log axis *has* to use math mode to typeset exponents.